# How to get nearest point on scene mesh to playerr mesh in urho3d?

Tags: gravity, urho3d

How to get nearest point on scene model mesh to player model mesh in urho3d?

I want to make gravity like in mario galaxy. I tried to get direction to mesh center, but if I have complicated geometry, I think I need closest point on mesh and get normal of it instead of mesh center. I think I need perpendicular direction to the scene surface.

```
void Character::RaycastToWorld()
{
    RigidBody* body = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    Vector3 bodyUpPos = body->GetPosition();
    Vector3 castRayVec = worldNode_->GetWorldPosition() - bodyUpPos;
    Vector3 castRayN = castRayVec.Normalized();

    curDistToWorld_ = castRayVec.Length();
    prevDirToCenterWorld_ = dirToCenterWorld_;

    PhysicsRaycastResult result;
    GetScene()->GetComponent<PhysicsWorld>()->RaycastSingle(result, Ray(bodyUpPos, castRayN), curDistToWorld_, ColMask_WorldRayCast);

    if (result.body_)
    {
        dirToCenterWorld_ = result.normal_ * -1.0f;
        curDistToWorld_ = result.distance_;
    }
}
```